# How can find numbers in html table with using search/filter?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function searchFunction(){
 let tabel, filter, input, tr, td, i;
 input = document.getElementById("myInput");
 filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
 tabel = document.getElementById("myTable");
 tr = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
 
 for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
            if (td) {
                if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            } 
        }
}
```

```css
.search_input {
 background-image: url(search_icon.png);
 background-position: 3px 9px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 12px 12px;
 width: 15%;
    height: 31px;
    padding: 12px 8px 9px 26px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    margin: 12px 0 12px 0;
    border-radius: 7px;
}
.my_tabel {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%; 
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    font-size: 13px; 
}
.my_tabel th, .my_tabel td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 12px; 
}

.my_tabeltr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; 
}

#myTable tr.header, #myTable tr:hover {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
table, .line{
 border: 1px solid;
}
thead
{
 background-color: #93B6D2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Assingment 3</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="js-assingment.css" type="text/css"/>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="js_module.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 </head>
 <body>
  <form name="searching_tabel" id="searching_tabel">
   <div class="container">
    <span>Search</span>
    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="searchFunction()" class="search_input">
    <table class="table table-bordered my_tabel" id="myTable">
      <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>#</th>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Email</th>
       <th>Date</th>
       <th>Courses</th>
       <th>UserGuid</th>
       <th>License</th>
     </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
     <tr>
       <th scope="row">1</th>
       <td>Mark Scheid</td>
       <td>mscgei@wgu.edu</td>
       <td>06-jan-15</td>
       <td>PK0-003-Project+</td>
       <td>03ocb</td>
       <td>Course</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <th scope="row">2</th>
       <td>Kenneth Nagle</td>
       <td>knagle@wgu.edu</td>
       <td>06-jan-15</td>
       <td>N10-005 CompTIA Network+</td>
       <td>02Oki</td>
       <td>Course</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <th scope="row">3</th>
       <td>Kenneth</td>
       <td>matt.bearce@verizonwireless.com</td>
       <td>06-jan-15</td>
       <td>Pearson-220-802-complete-Pearson CompTIA: A+ 220-802(Course & Lab)</td>
       <td>030c8</td>
       <td>Course</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <th scope="row">4</th>
       <td>Rafael Moreno</td>
       <td>rmoren4@wgu.edu</td>
       <td>06-jan-15</td>
       <td>N10-005 CompTIA Network+</td>
       <td>030c7</td>
       <td>Course</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <th scope="row">5</th>
       <td>Paul Doyle</td>
       <td>doylepaul@gmail.com</td>
       <td>06-jan-15</td>
       <td>Pearson-220-802-complete-Pearson CompTIA: A+ 220-801(Course & Lab)</td>
       <td>030c6</td>
       <td>Course</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <th scope="row">6</th>
       <td>Paul Doyle</td>
       <td>esmally@gmail.com</td>
       <td>06-jan-15</td>
       <td>Pearson-220-802-complete-Pearson CompTIA: A+ 220-801(Course & Lab)</td>
       <td>030bb</td>
       <td>Course</td>
     </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
   </div> 
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

I created a search/filter in html table. When I write a related alphabet in search input, it searches and shows information. But when I write a numbers in my search, no result are found.

Comment: Do you want to search from `first column` only? I dont see any issue in code

Comment: Only first column is searched. You don't have digits there.

Comment: Exactly, I think you need to loop through all columns and it will work

Answer (score 1):

As others mention you can use **Jquery Datatable** which offers a lot of in-built functionalities.

But if you still want to use pure javascript then use the below function to search through all the columns.

```
function searchFunction() {
    let tabel, filter, input, tr, td, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    tabel = document.getElementById("myTable");
    tr = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {
        if (tr[i].textContent.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            tr[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Also add `onsubmit="return false;"` to the form tag, so that the page doesn't reload when enter is pressed.